# How to set a postgres timestamp column based on a unix integer in a jsonb column?

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to update my database to pull a unix epoch integer out of a jsonb object and set a time stamp column with the value. I have some of the pieces, but I'm having trouble pulling it all together. Here's where I'm at (where subscription_end is a timestamp column and json_data is a jsonb column):

```
UPDATE "customers" SET "subscription_end" = to_timestamp(
    json_data -> 'some_property' ->> 'subscription_end'
);
```

I'm not sure if I have everything in the right order. I can't find any good examples of using the to_timestamp function together with a json drilldown like I am doing above.

Comment: Probably have to add a cast: `to_timestamp((json_data -> 'some_property' ->> 'subscription_end')::integer);`. The only way to know is try, preferably with a `WHERE` on the `UPDATE` to restrict what you are updating.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This was it:

```
UPDATE "customers" SET "subscription_end" = 
    to_timestamp((json_data -> 'some_property' ->> 'subscription_end')::integer);
```